# Find three Numbers with Sum closest to a given number

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, search, data-structures

I am trying to solve a problem where,

> Given an array S of n integers, find three integers in S such that the
>   sum is closest to a given number, target. Return the sum of the three
>   integers. You may assume that each input would have exactly one
>   solution.
>
> ```
> For example, given array S = {-1 2 1 -4}, and target = 1.
>
> The sum that is closest to the target is 2. (-1 + 2 + 1 = 2).
> ```

My solution is: take a number out (number_1) from the array, set the target to target - that number and find two other numbers which are closest to the new target. This way: number_1 + number_2 + number_3 will be closest as number_2 + number_3 will be closest to target - number_1.

I tried my solution at https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum-closest/description/.

My solution is:

```
def threeSumClosest(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    closest_sum = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]

    for i in range(len(nums)):

        # Create temp array excluding a number

        if i!=len(nums)-1:
            temp = nums[:i] + nums[i+1:]

        else:
            temp = nums[:len(nums)-1]


        # Sort the temp array and set new target to target - the excluded number

        temp = sorted(temp)            
        l, r = 0, len(temp) -1 
        t = target - nums[i]

        while(l<r):

            if temp[l] + temp[r] == t:
                return target

            elif temp[l] + temp[r] > t:

                if abs(temp[l] + temp[r] + nums[i] - target) < abs(closest_sum - target):
                    closest_sum = temp[l] + temp[r] + nums[i]

                r = r - 1

            else:

                if abs(temp[l] + temp[r] + nums[i] - target) < abs(closest_sum - target):
                    closest_sum = temp[l] + temp[r] + nums[i]

                l = l + 1


        return closest_sum
```

It passes 80 test cases out of 125, so the solution logic looks fine enough for me.

It fails for:

```
Input:
[0,2,1,-3]
1
Output:
3
Expected:
0
```

Can't understand why it fails and how to make my logic consistent.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking what is wrong with your code or are you asking for a better solution?

Comment: @RoryDaulton any will be great. I couldn't think of any better solution? Using hashing?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but you don't seem to update `closest` in your `else` branch in the `while` loop.

Comment: The lack of comments and self-documenting variable names makes it extremely difficult to understand what your algorithm is and just what your program is doing. Could you improve your code?

Comment: @PaulPanzer yes, that is a mistake. I tried updated code and still get the error at the same input

Comment: @mourinho dedenting the last return statement might also help ;-)

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks, I have updated the code.. plz comment if something is not clear... I have mentioned the algorithm at a high level in the question description.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Hi, thanks. It was the exact error. Dedenting (is is the opposite of identing?) the return closest_sum just fixed the problem. plz put it as the answer. Also, any suggestions to improve the algorithm? Is n squared log n the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we worked out in the comments the last `return` statment was erroneously inside the `for` loop cutting it short after the first iteration.
Also, `closest` should be updated in both branches where we overshoot or undershoot the target.

I think an obvious improvement of your algorithm would be to sort first. Removing individual elements doesn't destroy order, so you'd need to sort only once. That would get you from O(n^2 log n) to O(n^2).

Comment: thanks that improves complexity. I tried the new solution with sorting first: it beats 24% of python submissions in runtime. The earlier slower solution of n squared log n complexity was beating 76% of the solutions in runtime... how could this be happening? Any possible reasons. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mourinho Maybe it's because in the outer loop you are now picking the smallest elements first which may statistically speaking a bad choice? Are there many cases where the target can actually be matched exactly? You could try and in the outer loop move from the middle outwards.

Answer (score 3):

You have couple of mistakes the first one is silly, you have an extra indentation in `return closest` and the second one is not checking updating `closest` in the 3rd if statement.
This code got accepted:

```
class Solution(object):
def threeSumClosest(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    closest = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2]

    #if len(nums)==3:
    #    return closest

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i!=len(nums)-1:
            temp = nums[:i] + nums[i+1:]
        else:
            temp = nums[:len(nums)-1]

        temp = sorted(temp)

        l, r = 0, len(temp) -1 
        t = target - nums[i]

        while(l < r):
            if abs(temp[l] + temp[r] + nums[i] - target) < abs(closest - target):
                    closest = temp[l] + temp[r] + nums[i]

            if temp[l] + temp[r] == t:

                return target
            elif temp[l] + temp[r] > t:
                r = r - 1
            else:
                l = l + 1

    return closest
```

And this is an accepted C++ solution with `O(n^2)` running time:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int threeSumClosest(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        int ans = nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2];
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++) {
            int l = i + 1, r = nums.size() - 1;

            while (l < r) {
                if(abs(nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r] - target) < abs(target - ans)) {
                    ans = nums[i] + nums[l] + nums[r];
                }
                if(nums[r] + nums[l] > target - nums[i]) r = r - 1;
                else l = l + 1;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all combinations of values in the list, and then find the listing whose sum is closest to the target:

```
import itertools
s = [{'vals':[-1, 2, 1, -4], 'target':1}, {'vals':[0,2,1,-3],'target':1}]
final_result = {tuple(a['vals']):sum(min(itertools.combinations(a['vals'], 3), key=lambda x:abs(a['target']-sum(x)))) for a in s}
```

Output:

```
{(-1, 2, 1, -4): 2, (0, 2, 1, -3): 0}
```

Comment: And how is this different that the brute force solution?

Comment: @Ajax1234 thanks. but trying all combinations will be inefficient, my solutions is n squared * log n. Trying all values will be n cubed i think

Comment: @MrGreen It is shorter :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution works for this input:

[0,2,1,-3]
1

Your closest sum variable is incorrect.  See my variable named "gap"

```
class Solution:
def threeSumClosest(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    sorted_nums = sorted(nums)
    gap = sorted_nums[len(nums)-1] * 10000
    solution = 0

    for pointer_1 in range(len(sorted_nums)):
        pointer_2 = pointer_1 + 1
        pointer_3 = len(sorted_nums) - 1
        while(pointer_2 < pointer_3):
            gap_n = abs((sorted_nums[pointer_1]+sorted_nums[pointer_2]+sorted_nums[pointer_3]) - target)
            add = (sorted_nums[pointer_1]+sorted_nums[pointer_2]+sorted_nums[pointer_3])
            if (gap_n < gap):
                solution = add
                gap = gap_n
            elif (target > add):
                pointer_2 = pointer_2 + 1
            else:
                pointer_3 = pointer_3 - 1
    return solution
```